# Reading an online .tbl data file in python

Tags: python, datatable

Like the Title says, I am trying to read an online data file that is in .tbl format. Here is the link to the data: https://irsa.ipac.caltech.edu/data/COSMOS/tables/morphology/cosmos_morph_cassata_1.1.tbl

I tried the following code

```
cosmos= pd.read_table('https://irsa.ipac.caltech.edu/data/COSMOS/tables/morphology/cosmos_morph_cassata_1.1.tbl')
```

Running this didn't give me any errors however when I wrote `print (cosmos.column)`, it didn't give me a list of individuals columns instead python put everything together and gave me the output that looks like:

```
Index(['|            ID|            RA|           DEC|  MAG_AUTO_ACS|       R_PETRO|        R_HALF|    CONC_PETRO|     ASYMMETRY|          GINI|           M20|   Axial Ratio|     AUTOCLASS|   CLASSWEIGHT|'], dtype='object').
```

My main goal is to print the columns of that table individually and then print `cosmos['RA']`. Anyone know how this can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file has four header rows and different delimiters in header (`|`) and data (whitespace). You can read the data by using `skiprows` argument of `read_table`.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

filename = 'cosmos_morph_cassata_1.1.tbl'
url = 'https://irsa.ipac.caltech.edu/data/COSMOS/tables/morphology/' + filename
n_header = 4

## Download large file to disc, so we can reuse it...
table_file = requests.get(url)
open(filename, 'wb').write(table_file.content)


## Skip the first 4 header rows and use whitespace as delimiter
cosmos = pd.read_table(filename, skiprows=n_header, header=None, delim_whitespace=True)

## create header from first line of file
with open(filename) as f:
    header_line = f.readline()
    ## trim whitespaces and split by '|'
    header_columns = header_line.replace(' ', '').split('|')[1:-1]

cosmos.columns = header_columns
```

[image]